# could not connect to aws services using aws-cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am new to aws, I am trying to use aws-cli to connect aws as I am confortable with commandline, and want to use to write the script to automate the process.

However I am getting error as below:

```
_
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com/"
2017-07-08 20:30:52,763 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com/"
```

I have setup the profile user as in the config file.

```
[profile joey2]
output = json
region = ap-southeast-1a
```

the credential such as api key and secret is configured properly.

Could someone help to figure out what is cause of this issue.
highly appreciate for any advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ap-southeast-1a` is not a valid AWS Region, you need to use `ap-southeast-1` instead. You're getting that connection error because https://ec2.ap-southeast-1a.amazonaws.com/ (which is what your input region is attempting to resolve to) does not exist. You can verify this via the [EC2 Region documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region).

**Region Name:** Asia Pacific (Singapore)
**Region:** ap-southeast-1
**Endpoint:** ec2.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

### Further Reading

- [AWS Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)

Comment: @Van, to explain... `ap-southeast-1a` is an Availability Zone within the `ap-southeast-1` region. The AWS CLI connections to a regional endpoint that connects to all Availability Zones in the region, so you only need to the region name. It's a common error that people make.

Comment: yeah, that is very beginer mistake, I have fixed it and it is working as cham now.

Comment: It is easy to get lost because it is ap-southeast-1a that shows up in the "availability zone" column in AWS.