# AWS CLI unable to run commands because of connection error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I ventured asking this question because I am getting the following error when I try to run any command in aws cli

`Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://mturk-requester.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/"`

I am in norhtern California and my config file reads:

`region = us-west-1`

`output = table`

Therefore I am not experiencing the 1a error described in the questions already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409683/aws-s3-cli-could-not-connect-to-the-endpoint-url) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44986296/could-not-connect-to-aws-services-using-aws-cli).

I am also able to communicate with the server using all the steps described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-could-not-connect-endpoint-url/).

The commands I've been attempting to run are:

`aws mturk get-account-balance`

`aws mturk list-hits`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because `mturk` is only available in `us-east-1` which is also considered the AWS global region, this is [mentioned in the documentation for the SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html) and the only region mentioned on the [endpoints page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/amt.html).

> Configure the AWS SDK to use the ‘us-east-1’ region. This is the region in which the MTurk API is available.

If you specify the `--region` flag and set the value to `us-east-1` it should be able to connect to the mechanical turk endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to go through so much documentation to set aws that I completely went over this. So greatly appreaciated!

Comment: No problem have a great day :)